# Why does Django fail when Memcached goes down?

Tags: django

I'm running a Django 1.3 instance with a memcached backend for a caching layer, recently I've been trying to debug a part of the database for the application, but whenever I take the memcached server offline, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /joinerysoft/contacts/ajax/all/None/None/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://joinerysoft-directory.co.uk/joinerysoft/contacts/ajax/all/None/None/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/memcache.py in send_cmd, line 1112
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

I thought the attractive part of memcached + django is that if the memcache disappears, your site will still function (albeit crippled) until it returned. I do use Django's Built in Caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not an error from Django, but from the python-memcached library. 
Second I think this behaviour is consistent. If you configured Django to use memcached and it goes down, then it should throw an error! Assuming your site depends heavily on cache, you also want to know ASAP if something happens and not figure out a couple days later that your whole DB is down as well because there where too many queries (as an example).

There are ways to define a fallback cache or do other workarounds. Check out this similiar question: [Is there a way to ignore Cache errors in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515886/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-cache-errors-in-django)

Comment: So it should remove service totally, rather than degrading gracefully? seems to me like thats bad design. of course you want to know that your memcached servers are all down, and that you're running on DB alone, but isn't that better handled via error logging mechanisms, rather than erroring out to users

Comment: @Jharwood I think you can always build a wrapper that would handle these errors gracefully.

Comment: Yes, you are somehow right that it should be handled in the underlying library. In any case it should give you a warning at least (not necessarily an error), so you could configure Django to forward these warnings to you.

Comment: So it means whenever we used the cache, then we should 100% rely on it? Then what is the usage of being called "cache", doesn't it means that it should be ok though there is no the "cache", why it become block and cause error for everything?

Comment: If you use a DB you are also relying on it. If the database goes down your application will most likely fail as well, except you build error handlers around it, which will make you application fail gracefully. A cache backend is just another third-party data store. If you want to not rely on 100%, them build this into your application, but don't require the library or the tool itself to handle this for you. Again, I believe it is better to have explicit errors and then handle them accordingly.

Comment: But a Database and a cache backend are serving different purposes in the app. The database is source of truth for the app. If it is missing there is no way to get data. A cache is a performance optimization. If it is not available, you can still find the data somewhere. It's expected the cache will sometimes miss, an this will not logically change the output.. Causing the app to loose reliability when the optimization is not available is perverse

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't the question. If this is not built-in the library then you have to work out how to deal with cache misses. Catching an exception and handling it accordingly is the most straight-forward way and also very pythonic. Since the use case for a cache can be different in the end, the fall back solution is pretty much a custom implementation.